# Patch method in a package that is shadowed in __init__.py

Tags: python

I have a folder structure like this:

```
├─ some_module/
│  ├─ __init__.py
│  ├─ module.py
├─ main.py
```

With the sub-module being shadowed by its content:

```
# __init__.py
from .module import module

__all__ = ["module"]
```

```
# module.py
def module_b():
   print("In module_b")
    
def module():
    print("In module")
    module_b()
```

```
# main.py
from some_module.module import module
module()
```

The output of `main.py`:

```
In module
In module_b
```

I want to patch the method `module_b()` from `main.py` with the method `lambda: print("other module")` (leaving the content of `some_module` folder as it is). Expected output after running `main.py`:

```
In module
other module
```

How can this be done?

Comment: You mean you want to change `module_b` function body from `main`. Am I right ?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I think you should roll back that - the name collision is relevant to the question.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi The point is that `some_module.module` resolves to a function instance, not the submodule. So the obvious patch doesn't work, you're just setting an attribute in the function's namespace (since functions carry around a `__dict__` too).

Comment: Yes, the names are insane, and it might be that the O.P. even _intends_ to trip up / confuse. Nonetheless, it's a valid (and interesting) question :)

Comment: @wim Indeed. I've adjusted the wording a bit to make the collision more obvious. Hope this fits better now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is like this:

```
# main.py
import sys
from some_module.module import module
sys.modules["some_module.module"].module_b = lambda: print("other module")
module()
```